# Почему ajax запрос завершается с ошибкой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

У меня есть REST контроллер, который может удалять/вставлять/редактировать данные из бд, отображаю на jsp странице таблицу с соответствующими кнопками, использую jq. Мне нужно добавлять/удалять/редактировать строки таблицы без перезагрузки страницы, я использую ajax запросы. Адекватно работает только удаление, редактирование еще не добавил, неадекватно работает добавление объекта. Сам объект добавляется в бд и метод `save` контроллера возвращает вставленный объект с `id`(id генерирую на уровне бд)и после перезагрузки страницы он отрисовывается в таблице. Объект я не могу добавить просто в таблицу с помощью jquery потому что запрос ajax'a на добавление завершается в секции `error` и не передается в `response`.Приложу код скрипта и скрин ошибки, потому что я не знаю как ее можно описать словами.

```
<script>
        var LIST_PRODUCTS = "/listProducts";

        $(document).ready(function() {

        var table = $('table');
        //ДЛЯ ОТРИСОВКИ ТАБЛИЦЫ
        function showTable() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: LIST_PRODUCTS,
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    for (var i in result) {
                        var str = "<tr>";
                        for (var prop in result[i]) {
                            str += "<td>" + result[i][prop] + "</td>";
                        }
                        str += "<td><a href='#' data-id='" + result[i].id + "' class='delete'>удалить</a></td>";
                        str += "<td><a href='/' data-id='" + result[i].id + "' class='edit'>редактировать</a></td>";
                        str += "</tr>";
                        table.append(str);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Exception on out");
                }
            });
        }
showTable();

            //УДАЛЕНИЕ
            $(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
                var row = $(this).closest('td').parent();
                console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: LIST_PRODUCTS + "/delete/" + $(this).attr("data-id"),
                    async: true,
                    success: function (result) {
                        row.remove();
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Exception in DELETE")
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#form').submit(function () {
                sendAjaxForm();
                console.log(response);
            });

            function sendAjaxForm() {
                var DATA = {
                    name: $("#name").val(),
                    description: $("#description").val(),
                    create_date: $("#create_date").val(),
                    place_storage: $("#place_storage").val(),
                    reserved: $("#reserved").val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: LIST_PRODUCTS + "/create",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(DATA),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: true,
                    success: function (response) {
                        alert(response)
                    },
                    error: function (res) {
                        alert(res);
                    }
                });
            }

            $('.js-button-create').click(function() {
                $('.js-overlay-create').fadeIn();
                $('.js-overlay-create').addClass('disabled');
            });

            // закрыть на крестик
            $('.js-close-create').click(function() {
                $('#reset').click();
                $('.js-overlay-create').fadeOut();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой `alert` выполняется - из тех, что есть в коде? Используйте `console.log` вместо `alert`. Что возвращает `create`? Уберите `dataType: "json",`.

Comment: Почему, убрать dataType?

Comment: Не скажу, пока Вы не ответите на мои вопросы.

Comment: Что возвращает `create`?

Comment: Json объект, который передаю с формы, но возвращает уже со сгенерированым id

Comment: Вы заменили `alert`-ы на `console.log`? Что появляется в консоли браузера?

Comment: Да, ошибки нет. На самом деле она была, у меня не случайно там алерты стоят. все было так, как на скринах, у меня не было вообще секции `success` и была только `error`, так вот после получения ответа все передавалось именно в секцию `error`. Вот потом я начал мудрить с разным количеством секций success/done/error. Но потом решил это оставить на время и заняться удалением, когда там все получилось, занялся снова этой проблемой, но она куда-то сама ушла.

Comment: @Igor, так что с dataType?

Comment: Я исходил из того, что Вы сказали правду ), и ошибка действительно проводила к выполнению обработчика `error`. Так как, по Вашим словам, на сервере все выполнялось, наиболее вероятной причиной ошибки были данные ответа не в формате JSON.

Comment: @Igor, да, в тот момент когда я точно знал, что это ошибка и она таковой являлась, мой контроллер не присылал мне `json`, у метода-обработчика был тип `void`. Но все равно, почему запрос считался некоректным? Я щас воспроизвел эту ситуацию. Если мой метод-обработчик контроллера имеет тип `void` и я посылаю ему запрос `post`, метод-обработчик также принимает `post`, то происходит эта ошибка. Запрос считается проваленным, хотя он достучался до контроллера и отправил данные.

Comment: Ошибка происходит на клиенте, когда данные из ответа не могут быть распарсены как JSON. Поэтому я предлагал убрать указание на то, какого формата ожидаются данные. В таком случае параметром в `success` подается просто текст ответа.